# Google Action is 'deploying'

Tags: actions-on-google

My action has been approved. However, in the deployment history, I see that it is "deploying" for the last 3 days. I am not sure when that would be deployed. Should I be doing something to fix

Comment: Has your action been deployed yet? I'm in the same boat and wondering how long yours took.

Comment: I sent the customer support an email and they deployed the application after couple of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you need to do at this point - it is in the process of being made available to everyone. This process can sometimes take a few days, and can sometimes wait until they send out email advertising new Actions, but your Action can be live at any time!